# Jquery plugin and link_to rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I bought plugin for hover effect but it have something like this in html:

```
<a data-zl-popup="link" href="#"></a>
```

How can i set that type in link_to ... i try with data: { } but it dont let me put "zl-popup" in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "", '#', 'data-zl-popup' => 'link' %>
```

In HTML :

```
<a href="#" data-zl-popup="link"></a>
```